# How to write if condition in when condition - PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to add an if condition in F. when in a pyspark column
my code:

```
df = df.withColumn("column_fruits",F.when(F.col('column_fruits') == "Berries"
if("fruit_color")==  "red": 
   return "cherries" 
elif("fruit_color") == "pink": 
   return "strawberries"
else:
   return "balackberries").otherwise("column_fruits")
```

I want to first filter out berries and change fruit names according to color. And all the remaining fruits remain the same.
Can anyone tell me if this is a valid way of writing `withColumn` code?

Comment: You can use "and"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
df.withColumn("column_fruits", F.when((F.col('column_fruits') == "Berries") & (F.col('fruit_color') == "red"), "cherries")\
          .when((F.col('column_fruits') == "Berries") & (F.col('fruit_color') == "pink"), "strawberries")\
          .otherwise("blackberries"))\
          .show()
```

Sample Input/Output:

[image: Output]